# Quartz CGEvent mouse click not working anymore

Tags: swift, macos, appkit, mouseclick-event, nsevent

I made a command line tool years ago that worked fine up until macOS Monterey. The code below no longer works for a command line tool. It works fine if I use a macOS application. I need a command line tool so I can trigger the executable from Dictation.

(sandbox settings in Xcode is turned off. Also, Privacy > Accessibility is allowed in System Preferences)

```
var ml = NSEvent.mouseLocation
ml.y = NSHeight(NSScreen.screens[0].frame) - ml.y
let location = CGPoint(x: ml.x, y: ml.y)

let eventDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: location, mouseButton: .left)
eventDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

let eventUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: location, mouseButton: .left)
eventUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

Comment: How do you launch your command-line tool? If it's from Terminal, try giving Terminal.app accessibility permissions

Comment: Have you created an Info.plist for the command line tool (with a proper `CFBundleIdentifier`) and enabled the option to `Create Info.plist Section in Binary`?